# add Menu type for Virtue Mart component in Joomla

Tags: joomla1.5, joomla-extensions, virtuemart, joomla-template

I installed VM manually and the menu type is missing from the list. How can i add this manually. I understand i have to use views but i don't have a views folder for the component.Do i need to create a view for it if so how do i need to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in the jos_components table and see if you have a record for VM. If not, then use this -

```
INSERT INTO `jos_components` (`name`, `link`, `menuid`, `parent`, `admin_menu_link`, `admin_menu_alt`, `option`, `ordering`, `admin_menu_img`, `iscore`, `params`, `enabled`) VALUES
('VirtueMart', 'option=com_virtuemart', 0, 0, 'option=com_virtuemart', 'VirtueMart', 'com_virtuemart', 0, '../components/com_virtuemart/shop_image/ps_image/menu_icon.png', 0, '', 1);
```

Comment: Thanks much. I have the menu type showing but the other steps of the checkout are not using the VM menu like i would expect

Comment: Do you have a VM menu item created? Do you have the VM module published? Those are both required for VM to work right.

Comment: which module should i publish. I have VM best sales, VM categories?

Comment: In the module manager, you should have a module called simply Virtuemart Module. You can put it in an invisible module position, but it has to be published because VM uses some of the settings in that module.

Comment: i installed and enabled the module and the other steps render on the homepage. They just push everything down and show on the homepage. I have VirtueMart 1.1.9 stable and the module mod_virtuemart_1.1.6.j15, do the versions have to match?

Comment: well i changed to the matching versions but no luck

Comment: Did you also create the menu or do you just have it showing up. You have to create a VM menu as well.

Comment: i created the menu. I ended up doing a reinstall as i managed to turn safe mode off and everything works fine for now. Thanks for your help.I appreciate it